# how to download linux kernel using rsync

Tags: rsync, linux-kernel

I tried git clone, but it's too slow, how to do it with rsync? is it faster?
If I do `rsync rsync://rsync.kernel.org/pub/`
it just shows:

```
drwxr-sr-x        4096 2011/11/16 04:40:02 kernel
```

Answer (score 4):

The command probably should be

```
$ rsync -av rsync://rsync.kernel.org/pub .
```

But, I doubt this is actually what you want to be doing. This will *completely mirror* the public parts of the kernel archive. You will get all versions of everything available, not just the current version.

Without seeing the `git clone` command, I'm guessing it's the one to download the kernel sources, only. Because of the way Git works, you will get all versions as well, but in a much, much more efficient way than an `rsync` mirror.

If you need something faster than a Git repository download, I suggest you just [download the latest release or RC version](http://kernel.org). That will get you a single version. You'll miss out on changes made since the last release or RC. If you need that, Git is the way to get it.